# Оживлен(н)а

Tags: орфография

При обсуждении "оживленного движения" обратил внимание на мнение Лопатина.

> оживлённый; кр. ф. прич. -ён, -ена; ***кр. ф. прил. -ён, -ена*** (испытывающий оживление: она весела и оживлена) и ***-ён, -ённа*** (обнаруживающий признаки оживления, выражающий оживление: беседа оживлённа, улицы оживлённы; лица гостей оживлённы)

курсив мой - b-s

Ранее разделение на Н/НН в кратких формах женского (и среднего) рода шло строго по линии причастие/прилагательное. Тут уже нечто другое.
Интуитивно понимаю, что Лопатин тут прав, еще Аванесов говорил о зыбкости этого критерия разделения по частям речи.

Но обосновать не могу. Из чего Лопатин исходит, давая такое написание? Или в чем он ошибается, если оно неверное?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это нюансы морфологии и её зависимости от значения слова.Лопатин и Зализняк считают, что причастие только со значением"оживлённый кем-то, возвращённый к жизни", а "испытывающий  оживление, исполненный жизни(переносн.)"-уже прилагательное, но отглагольное, связи с глаголом окончательно не потеряны(что-то его оживило), поэтому пишется так, как глагольная форма,-с одной -Н-: "Лиза ... была оживлена и счастлива только тогда, когда была влюблена". Л. Тлстй - она не просто весёлая, а под действием чего-то;

"обнаруживающий признаки оживления, веселья, возбуждения"-явное прилагательное от существительного"оживление",его никто не оживлял, он сам выражает признаки оживления(возбуждения) - беседа, улица, лица гостей.

Comment: Ясно. Т.е. ни о каких  новациях в плане собственно орфографии или её трактовке тут речи не идёт? Просто реализация различий между обычным и отглагольным прилагательными?   
Я не знал, что Зализняк того же мнения, одному Лопатину я бы не поверил до конца, при всем к нему уважении.     
Если не секрет, Вы реконструировали эту идею или где-то было прописано?

Comment: Просто посмотрела словари. Это не расходится и с моим мнением. Причастие и прилагательное - трудная тема в школе, многие её не понимают, нужно копаться в нюансах, что я и делаю. чтобы объяснить детям. Только  сейчас, чтобы их не путать, принято упрощать,Толстой не упрощал, он тонко чувствовал все оттенки слова.В современных книгах "она была оживлённа" наверняка напишут с двумя-Н-,тем более, что рядом однородное прилагательное"счастлива", что говорит о принадлежности к прилагательному.Приравняли сейчас отглагольное и отымённое прилагательные.

Comment: Я в своем ответе писал об **оттенках значений и формы слов**, но автор вопроса заминусовал мой ответ. Теперь же он на задних лапах принимает точно такой же ответ от Людмилы))) Браво!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Отрывок из моего ответа :

*Девушка была весела и* (чем-то) *оживлена*.

*Девушка была весела и оживлённа* (активна сама по себе, характер у нее такой)

Comment: Зачем же убрали свой ответ? Вот и сравнили бы. Про "задние лапы"- это Вы зря. Просто я сумела, видимо, убедить, а Вы нет. Не нужно разжигать страсти.

Comment: Бегемотус очень избирательно подходит к ответам различных участников. Он один и тот же мой ответ может сминусовать несколько раз, используя технологию форума. Убедить бегемотуса?? Не смешите, Людмила))) Просто Вы написали волшебное слово *Зализняк*, а я высказал свое личное понимание вопроса. Бегемотус таких вольностей не терпит, и Вы это знаете.

Comment: >Просто посмотрела словари.  
  
Людмила, но ни в одном словаре нет объяснения ***причин*** различий в написании тем более - в связи с ***морфологией***.  
Т.е., получается, что Вы все-таки реконструировали мысль Лопатина и/или Зализняка? 

ЗЫ Себя и grumant'а обсуждать не хочу. Это уже вопрос Администрации - и я догадываюсь, как он разрешится. А по сути, Вы ответили (попытались) ответить именно на ***мой вопрос***. И - правдоподобно. До "убеждения" пока еще далеко. Принял ответ поскольку через какое-то время сделать это скорее всего уже не смогу.

Comment: В словарях объяснений нет - у Розенталя есть. Что касается написания кратких форм - здесь действительно все зависит от оттенков значения. И правильное написание помогает понять мысль автора. Дети плохо воспитаны(причастие: их плохо воспитали; значение действия, прошедшее время)- дети воспитанны (прилагательное, синоним культурны, вежливы, тактичны и т.п.)

Comment: Ларf, спасибо, но можно посмотреть, где и что пишет Розенталь по вопросу различной орфографии конкретно в этом случае?   
Касательно Вашей формулировки все "зависит от оттенков значения". Я с ней не согласен. Нет такого правила, что написание определяется *оттенками значения*,  иначе и вопроса моего бы не было, да и самой орфографии как таковой. В данном контексте  это означало бы подмену причины следствием. 
В нашем случае - не от оттенков значения, а именно от *морфологии* (если вообще не от грамматики), если только принять версию Людмилы за истинную.  
И еще: интересует подход, не примеры.

Comment: Я что-то не понимаю до конца Ваши сомнения.

Comment: Ларf, я столько понаписал...  
Ничего не остаётся, воспользоваться советом писателя, на вопрос "О чем Ваше книга?" ответившего "А вы прочитайте!".

Answer (score 3):

Причастия могут переходить в прилагательные, теряя при этом глагольные признаки и приобретая качественность прилагательного. Поэтому сочетания с причастием можно заменить глаголом, а к отглагольному прилагательному подобрать в качестве синонимов  прилагательные.  Что и продемонстрировала Людмила в своем ответе. К сожалению, справочник Розенталя по орфографии и пунктуации у меня не дома, но в справочнике по литературной правке этот материал тоже рассматривается, возможно, немного в меньшем объеме.

Цитирую:

"7. В кратких формах страдательных причастий, в отличие от полных всегда пишется одно н, в кратких формах отглагольных прилагательных пишется столько н, сколько в полных формах. Ср.:

Демократическая общественность взволнована (причастие: ее взволновали) сообщениями о межнациональных столкновениях. — Игра актера была проникновенна и взволнованна (прилагательное: полна волнения).

Многие из них были приближены ко двору и возвышены (причастие: их возвысили). — Их идеалы и стремления были возвышенны (прилагательное: благородны и глубоки).

Их дети воспитаны (причастие: их воспитали) в духе передовых идей. — Манеры этой девушки свидетельствуют о том, что она тактична и воспитанна (прилагательное: умеющая хорошо себя вести).

Иногда простые вопросы бывают искусственно запутаны (причастие: их запутали). — Сюжеты этих произведений сложны и запутанны (прилагательное: трудны для понимания).

Вам всегда везет, вы, по-видимому, избалованы (причастие: вас избаловали) судьбой. — При неправильном воспитании дети обычно капризны и избалованны (прилагательное: испорчены баловством, капризны, изнежены).

Эти выводы обоснованы (причастие: их обосновали) самой логикой исследования. — Предъявленные нам требования произвольны и необоснованны (прилагательное: неубедительны).

Масштабы работ были ограничены (причастие: их ограничили) отпущенными средствами. — Его возможности ограниченны (прилагательное: малы).

Врачи были озабочены (причастие: их озаботило) состоянием больного. — Шторм усиливался, и лица моряков были серьезны и озабоченны (прилагательное: беспокойны).

Суд не усмотрел в данном деле состава преступления, и обвиняемые были оправданы (причастие: их оправдали). — Чрезвычайные меры в этих условиях были необходимы и вполне оправданны (прилагательное: имеющие объяснение).

Все варианты дальнейшей игры шахматистом до конца продуманы (причастие: он их продумал). — Ответы экзаменующихся были содержательны и продуманны (прилагательное: разумны, обоснованны).

Разве в скобках Розенталь не значение нам объясняет?

И я не согласна, что орфография не может зависеть от смысла. Очень даже может.  Кроме этой темы значение очень важно в выборе слитного-раздельного написания НЕ с прилагательными. Более того, правильное написание помогает понять значение написанного. Река неглубокая (=мелкая). Река не глубокая. (Отрицание глубины. Но вовсе не обязательно она будет мелкой. Может, так себе, вполне средняя).